# print the pattern between (and excluding) two pattern as many as occasion it appears

Tags: json, scripting, jq

print the pattern between (and excluding) two pattern as many as occasion it appears

***Input file***

```
$ cat /tmp/file.in
                "3": {
                    "cpumask": "0x000000003C000000",
                    "devices": [
                        "Samsung SSD 970 PRO 1TB               XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     01",
                        "Samsung SSD 970 PRO 1TB               XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     01",
                        "Samsung SSD 970 PRO 1TB               XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     01"
                    ]
                },
                "2": {
                    "cpumask": "0x0000000000060000",
                    "devices": [
                        "Samsung SSD 970 PRO 1TB               XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     01",
                        "Samsung SSD 970 PRO 1TB               XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     01"
                    ]
                },
```

tried but only prints the first occasion

```
$ sed '1,/devices/d;/]/,$d'  /tmp/sn310_dev.out
                        "Samsung SSD 970 PRO 1TB               XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     01",
                        "Samsung SSD 970 PRO 1TB               XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     01",
                        "Samsung SSD 970 PRO 1TB               XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     01"
```

Comment: If this is a json file then experts always advise to use tools like `jq` to process it which understands it better. Could you please do let us know if you have jq installed on your machine? Or you can install it, solutions could be given as per that in here, thank you.

Comment: Yes it is/ can be installed.

Comment: Can you post the whole JSON available? are the `"3"` and `"2"` nested under something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally your input would be json but if that's the contents of the file, jq won't be able to process as json without tweaking the input. Fortunately, not too much, just read the file as a string, "tweak it," parse `fromjson` and get the desired fields.

```
$ cat file.in
                "3": {
                    "cpumask": "0x000000003C000000",
                    "devices": [
                        "Samsung SSD 970 PRO 1TB               XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     01",
                        "Samsung SSD 970 PRO 1TB               XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     01",
                        "Samsung SSD 970 PRO 1TB               XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     01"
                    ]
                },
                "2": {
                    "cpumask": "0x0000000000060000",
                    "devices": [
                        "Samsung SSD 970 PRO 1TB               XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     01",
                        "Samsung SSD 970 PRO 1TB               XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     01"
                    ]
                },
$ </tmp/file.in jq -Rsr '"{\(sub("\\},$"; "}"))}" | fromjson[].devices[]' >/tmp/sn310_dev.out
$ cat /tmp/sn310_dev.out
Samsung SSD 970 PRO 1TB               XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     01
Samsung SSD 970 PRO 1TB               XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     01
Samsung SSD 970 PRO 1TB               XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     01
Samsung SSD 970 PRO 1TB               XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     01
Samsung SSD 970 PRO 1TB               XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX     01
```

Here, the switches `-R` and `-s` takes the entire input in as a string while `-r` outputs the results as a raw string.

```
"{\(sub("\\},$"; "}"))}"
```

Substitute the trailing `},` with a `}` and wrap all in `{}` to make it look like a json object.

```
fromjson[].devices[]
```

Parse the json object string to a value, and extract the values from the object and the values from each of the values' `devices` property.

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/d24L_9UrUM)